# Form design messed up when using Show()

Tags: c#, winforms, show, showdialog

I'm trying to make a loading screen window. I use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()` because I have some code to execute after showing it. When using `ShowDialog()` form is fine but when using `Show()` form is messed up. What is causing this and what is the solution? Here is how I did it:

```
    bool closeLoadingWindow = false;
    void ShowLoadingWindow()
    {
        LoadingWindow loadingWindow = new LoadingWindow();
        loadingWindow.Show();
        while (!closeLoadingWindow);
        loadingWindow.Close();
        return;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Thread loadingWindowThread = new Thread(ShowLoadingWindow);
        loadingWindowThread.Start();
        InitializeComponent();
        // ...
        closeLoadingWindow = true;
    }
```

When using `ShowDialog()`:

[image: image 1]

When using Show():

[image: image 2]

Comment: As your code shows, you are performing nothing after showing the form. so why don't you use ShowDialog() ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a message loop running: `Application.Run(...)`.

Comment: @Shaharyar, look closely, there is a while loop and after it I'm closing the form.

Comment: try while (!closeLoadingWindow) Application.DoEvents();

Comment: @LarsTech, I'm using Application.Run() to open MainWindow and it shows loading screen...

Comment: There are several problems here. What @LarsTech said for one. The other problem is you're doing UI work in a worker thread. That's just bad... Don't do that.

Comment: @Tommi, Application.DoEvents() helped, thanks.

Comment: @Pete, I'm creating a separate thread for showing loading form, how would you recommend to do it correctly?

Comment: To not do it on a separate thread. Google "GUI threads C#". You will find plenty of information explaining the problems and how to handle this stuff correctly. But bottom line, all GUI stuff needs to happen on the main thread. Any GUI work done on worker threads is likely to fail at some point if it doesn't fail immediately.

Comment: What does Application.DoEvents() ? just for knowledge

Comment: Application.DoEvents() pumps the message loop. WinForms apps are mere Win32 Windows apps. Under the covers they have a WndProc and a message loop pump much like  classic Windows C app. Here's a tutorial on the message loop: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `ShowDialog` is working is because your `while` loop won't be executing, once the runtime hits that line of code it will stop processing until the form is dimissed.

Your code doesn't make sense, the point of using a thread here is to keep the "busy" code (your `while` loop) out of the main UI thread so it doesn't block. However, you are trying to create/show your form on the *same* thread, and a non-UI thread at that.

You don't necessarily need to use `Show` here, you can use `ShowDialog` but it is a little bit trickier in terms of dimissing the form etc. However, to solve the problem you have at the minute I would recommend you do:

```
LoadingWindow _loadingWindow;

void ShowLoadingWindow()
{
    if (_loadingWindow == null)
        _loadingWindow = new LoadingWindow();
    _loadingWindow.Show();
}

void HideLoadingWindow()
{
    if (_loadingWindow != null)
    {
         _loadingWindow.Close();
         _loadingWindow.Dispose();
    }
}

void LoadSomething()
{
    while (...)
    {
        // busy code goes here
    }
    // after code is finished, close the form
    MethodInvoker closeForm = delegate { HideLoadingWindow(); };
    _loadingWindow.Invoke(closeForm);
}

public MainWindow()
{
    ShowLoadingWindow();
    new Thread(LoadSomething).Start();
}
}
```

FYI - Depending on the nature of exactly what your trying to do in the thread it might be a better approach to use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd460717.aspx) rather than creating a dedicated thread, various benefits like [continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) / [cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee372288.aspx) support.

Comment: some questions: why there is while loop in LoadSomething if things are loading only once? Can I put MainWindow's InitializeComponent there?

Comment: @zgintasz the `LoadSomething` method is where your actual loading takes place (I assume your loading *something* at this point), this is the code that's executed on the worker thread, everything else runs on the UI thread so it doesn't block. You can put InitializeComponent in there if you want, however, I don't see what your gaining there by doing that? If you don't want the main form to be visible whilst your form is loading simply set it to hidden in the `ShowLoadingForm` and make it visible again in the `HideLoadingForm`

Comment: I put MainWindow's InitializeComponent in the LoadSomething: http://pastebin.com/duD3h1yK but I get an exception "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: I thought you were asking if you could put `InitializeComponent` in the `ShowLoadingForm` method, you can't call `InitializeComponent` on a different thread (unless you invoke it on the UI thread), however, again I don't know why you want to call this method during your load. What *exactly* is it your trying to do? At the moment it isn't 100% clear.

Comment: I'm trying to show a very simple form while the main window is loading(then I'll just close loading form and show main window form). Maybe InitializeComponent loads fast enough and I shouldn't put it in different place?

Comment: Is it really a splash screen your after here? I can't imagine it takes your main form *that* long to load (unless your actually doing something that takes long)? See how to [use the ApplicationContext class to fully encapsulate splash screen functionality](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5756/Use-the-ApplicationContext-Class-to-Fully-Encapsul)